# Composition in database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Hi this [article](http://i-proving.com/2010/11/30/unidirectional-one-to-many-using-a-join-column-hibernate/) author wrote:

> An IssueManagement can NOT exist without an Issue and as such seems to me well suited to using

So now why the foreign key from Issue table is not part of primary key in IssueManagement table?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because IssueMagement already have an autonumeric ID as primary key to make sure each row is unique.

Let me show you an example, but instead of number for ID I will use letters.

```
Isues     Issue Magament

ID    |    IDM  ID
 A    |     X    A  
 B    |     Y    B  
 C    |     Z    A
```

You only IDM to identify each `Issue Magament`row.

Comment: If IssueManagement can not exist without Issue, foreign key must be a part of primary key!  http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.docs_12.1.0/html/cdug/cdugp86.htm